# How to interact smart contract to my IOS and Android app

Tags: solidity, private-blockchain, dapp-development

I created a UI part on my android and IOS app and created a smart contract in solidity based on the application. When I click the button in android or Ios app contract need to executed in the backend. So that, I need to interact my smart contract with these apps

Answer (score 2):

With Android I was able to do so using the [web3j](https://docs.web3j.io/smart_contracts.html) library.  Here is my implementation in Android:

> Application:
>
> https://github.com/EbenezerGH/Greeter-Android-App
>
> Contract:
>
> https://github.com/EbenezerGH/Greeter-Contract

Dependencies used

```
api 'org.web3j:infura:3.3.1-android'
api 'org.web3j:core:3.1.1-android'
```

iOS has a similar implementations w/ [web3j](https://docs.web3j.io/smart_contracts.html)